# Gitlab on Synology with Docker

Tags: git, docker, server, gitlab, synology

I'm trying to install and setup GitLab on a Synology server. I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.golimb.com/2017/07/16/synology-docker-gitlab-redis-postgresql/). My issue is when I go to the GitLab page, I need to request a new password in order to activate my account (stupid idea). I set all the needed environment variables on the docker-compose.yml I checked all the logs and nothing inform me that something is wrong. However I never receive the email confirmation... Please help!

Here is my complete docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'

services:  
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    container_name: gitlab-redis
    command:
    - --loglevel warning
    volumes:
    - /volume1/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis

  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:10
    container_name: gitlab-postgresql
    volumes:
    - /volume1/docker/gitlab/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
    - DB_USER=xxx
    - DB_PASS=xxx
    - DB_NAME=xxx
    - DB_EXTENSION=xxx

  gitlab:
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    links:
    - redis
    - postgresql
    ports:
    - "10080:80"
    - "10022:22"
    volumes:
    - /volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
    - /volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
    - /volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/data:/home/git/data
    - /volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/opt:/var/opt/gitlab
    environment:
    - DB_ADAPTER=xxx
    - DB_HOST=xxx
    - DB_PORT=5432
    - DB_USER=xx
    - DB_PASS=xxx
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - REDIS_PORT=6379
    - TZ=Europe/Pais
    - GITLAB_TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris
    - GITLAB_HTTPS=false
    - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=8022
    - GITLAB_HOST=localhost
    - GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
    - GITLAB_ROOT_EMAIL=xxx
    - GITLAB_EMAIL_DISPLAY_NAME=x
    - GITLAB_EMAIL_SUBJECT_SUFFIX=xxx
    - GITLAB_EMAIL_ENABLED=true
    - GITLAB_EMAIL=xxx
    - GITLAB_EMAIL_REPLY_TO=xxx
    - GITLAB_INCOMING_EMAIL_ADDRESS=xxx
    - SMTP_ENABLED=true
    - SMTP_USER=xxx
    - SMTP_PASS=xxx
    - SMTP_DOMAIN=www.gmail.com
    - SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
    - SMTP_PORT=587
    - SMTP_STARTTLS=true
    - SMTP_AUTHENTICATION=plain
    - IMAP_ENABLED=true
    - IMAP_HOST=imap.gmail.com
    - IMAP_PORT=993
    - IMAP_USER=xxx@gmail.com
    - IMAP_PASS=xxx
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=xxx
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=xxx
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=xxx
```

Comment: This seems like a really complicated way to run GitLab. Have you considered using the GitLab CE image from GitLab (https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/)?

Comment: GitLab CE ok thanks I figure it out. However someone knows if I need to configure a Mail Server on my Synology in order to receive the email confirmation ? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to install/configure GitLab always with docker but on my mac. Exactly the same issue......